# how to deal with EMACS paste cascading

Tags: emacs

when I paste something into EMACS, like "Ctrl+V" then right mouse click into the EMACS screen, I frequently enter into this cascaded result

```
|  Xxxxxxx |  Xxxxxxx |  Xxxxxxx |     Xxxxxxx |
    |    10    |    39    |       Xxxxxxx  |    -1.0000     |
        |    10    |    51    |       Xxxxxxx |  -100001.0000  |
            |    10    |    55    |       Xxxxxxx |   -1000.0000   |
                |    10    |   407    |       Xxxxxxx |  -10000.0000   |
                    |    10    |   717    |       Xxxxxxx |    -10.0000    |
```

so I have to move cursor into each line and press "=" to align them

```
|  Xxxxxxx |  Xxxxxxx |       Xxxxxxx |     Xxxxxxx |
|    10    |    39    |       Xxxxxxx |    -1.0000     |
|    10    |    51    |       Xxxxxxx |  -100001.0000  |
|    10    |    55    |       Xxxxxxx |   -1000.0000   |
```

there should be a much quicker way, isn't it ?

Comment: From where do you copy and what? What mode do you use in Emacs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that you're inserting this text into an Emacs that's running inside a terminal emulator rather than as an X11/GUI application.  So the text you're inserting looks to Emacs like you're typing it at the keyboard, so all the line breaks are received by Emacs in the form of LF characters, which are ASCII chars also known in Emacs parlance as `C-j`, which is bound by default to `newline-and-indent`.  So you can circumvent this annoying effect with `(global-set-key [?\C-j] 'newline)` or you can switch to running Emacs as a GUI application.

Comment: yes, you are right. except for changing the configuration and restart, is there someway to toggle this setting?

Comment: @zinking: yes, there's a way, which is to run the code I showed.  More specifically, type `M-: (global-set-key [?\C-j] 'newline) RET` and this problem should disappear for the current session.  Note that other similar problems can still show up if the text you paste contain other control chars, such as TABs.

Comment: @zinking: To figure out why, we'd need to know the major mode you're using.  Also, try to manually type `| XXX | RET | 10` to see if the same indentation effect appears.